# SQL code for selecting values not present in other columns

Tags: sql

I have to find telephone numbers not available in other four columns. Telephone column contains special characters and extra prefix like 91 or +91.

```
select u.agreementnumber,SUBSTR(telephone,-10) as telephone,p.contact1,p.contact2,p.mobile1,p.mobile2 from BIUSR.TBL_TRN_CIBIL_ID_DETAILS u
left join cust_agmt_CA p
on u.agreementnumber=p.agmtno
where (u.telephone != p.mobile1) or (u.telephone != p.mobile2) or (u.telephone != p.contact1) or (u.telephone != p.contact2)
```

Result gives me telephone numbers with the same mobile number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace OR with AND condition to ensure the mobile number is not available in any of the four columns.

```
SELECT u.agreementnumber, 
   SUBSTR(telephone, -10) AS telephone, 
   p.contact1, 
   p.contact2, 
   p.mobile1, 
   p.mobile2
FROM BIUSR.TBL_TRN_CIBIL_ID_DETAILS u
LEFT JOIN cust_agmt_CA p ON u.agreementnumber = p.agmtno
WHERE(u.telephone != p.mobile1)
 AND (u.telephone != p.mobile2)
 AND (u.telephone != p.contact1)
 AND (u.telephone != p.contact2);
```

Comment: @Vishal, Please add your concern in comment other than editing my Answer.

Comment: Still there are matching telephone numbers in two coloumns. How to remove special characters in same statement

Comment: Do you need unique phone number considering all 5 columns? Currently its just ensuring u.telephone is not available in any other 4 columns. But other 4 columns may have same Phone number in them.

Comment: Should I use and or or. I think or is answer

Comment: For what? To check u.telephone is available in any of other four columns, AND is appropriate as defined in my query. But if you want some other logic to apply, please explain those logic.

Comment: Ok your logic is correct but how it will differ when used or

Comment: If you use OR, row will return if any of the checking return TRUE. For example if it found (u.telephone != p.mobile1) is TRUE, query will not check other 3 option and this is possible of having the Phone number in any of other 3 columns. OR only check if any of the condition is TRUE or not. Where as AND condition ensure all the conditions are TRUE.